# .net framework 4.6.2: System.TypeInitializationException:““Npgsql.TypeMapping.GlobalTypeMapper”

Tags: c#, postgresql

This is my code:

```cs
public void Select()
{
    using (NpgsqlConnection con = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        con.Open();
        //...other code
    }
}
```

When this program reaches `con.Open()`, it reports an error

> System TypeInitializationException: Error in 'NpgSQL. TypeMapping. GlobalTypeMapper'

What I am doing is secondary development of BimBase. When I use a new .NET framework program, it can run, but when I enter the command from BimBase, it will report this error.

1. I have tried to adjust the version of `NpgSQL.dll`, but neither 4.1.7 nor 4.1.12 worked
2. I have loaded the dependencies according to Nuget's instructions, but it still doesn't work
3. I have already configured `<assemblyBinding>` in `app.config`, but this cannot solve the problem either

Comment: Need to upgrade NpgSQL